# La vista no manda datos al controlador

Tags: c#

Esperando me puedan ayudar.

Tengo el problema de que al enviar los datos de mi vista al metodo Crear [tipo POST] (por ahora estoy mandado algunos dummies).

Mi controlador deberia recibir el objeto de tipo SolicitudViewModel con los datos que se hayan llenado pero sin embargo, este recibe todos sus objetos en nulo. Supongo que no esta haciendo el binding de datos, pero ya revise la sintaxis tanto del controlador como de la vista y yo no veo ningun problema.

Estoy utilizando EntityFramework 6 con .NET Framework 4.6.0 
Muchas gracias de antemano

El codigo es el siguiente.

Codigo del Controlador y clases necesarias

```
 public class SolicitudViewModel
    {
        public Solicitud Solicitud { get; set; }
        public SolicitudPermiso SolicitudPermiso { get; set; }
        public SolicitudVacaciones SolicitudVacaciones { get; set; }
    }

public class SolicitudController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Solicitud
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Crear()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Crear(SolicitudViewModel solicitud)
        /*
          Aqui recibe (cuando no deberia)
          solicitud.Solicitud como null
          solicitud.SolicitudPermiso como null
          solicitud.SolicitudVacaciones como null
        */
        {
            if (!SolicitudNegocio.Crear(solicitud))
            {
                return View();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

Codigo de la vista

```
<div class="right_col" role="main" id="solicitud">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Mis días de vacaciones</h3>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Crear", "Solicitud", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Tipo de Solicitud</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0px;">
                            <div class="input-group" id="TipoSolicitud">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Solicitud.Tipo,
                                    new List<SelectListItem>
                                    {
                                        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Elija uno por favor", Value = "0" },
                                        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Vacaciones", Value = "1" },
                                        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Permiso", Value = "2" }
                                    },
                                    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "Tipo" }
                                )
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Solicitud.Tipo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="right_col" role="main" id="vacaciones" style="min-height:initial">
                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Mis días de vacaciones</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 0px;">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-striped2">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="text-center">Días tomados</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Días disponibles</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Días por vencer</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class="text-center">

                                        @if (false)
                                        {

                                            <tr>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td id="iDiasDisponibles"></td>
                                                <td></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="3" class="text-center">No hay registro de vacaciones</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Del:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0px;">
                                <div class="input-group date" id="dpkFechaInicio" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.SolicitudVacaciones.FechaInicio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", @required = "required" } })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">al:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0px;">
                                <div class="input-group date" id="dpkFechaFinal" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.SolicitudVacaciones.FechaFinal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", @required = "required" } })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Deberás presentarte el:</label>
                        <div id="tFechaPresentarse" class="col-sm-8">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.SolicitudVacaciones.FechaPresentarse, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Días a disfrutar:</label>
                        <div id="iDiasDisfrutar" class="col-sm-2">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.SolicitudVacaciones.DiasDisfrutar, new
                            {
                                htmlAttributes = new
                                {
                                    @class = "form-control",
                                    type = "text"@*, disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly"*@ }
                            })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Días pendientes:</label>
                        <div id="iDiasPendientes" class="col-sm-2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="iDiasPendientes" readonly>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Días fuera de periodo:</label>
                        <div id="iDiasFueraPeriodo" class="col-sm-2">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.SolicitudVacaciones.DiasFueraPeriodo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input id="enviarSolicitudVacaciones" type="submit" value="Enviar solicitud" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="right_col" role="main" id="permisos">
                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Permisos</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Del:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0px;">
                                    <div class="input-group" id="dpkFechaInicio" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.SolicitudPermiso.FechaInicio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", @required = "required" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">al:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0px;">
                                    <div class="input-group date" id="dpkFechaFinal" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.SolicitudPermiso.FechaFin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", @required = "required" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Deberás presentarte el:</label>
                            <div id="tFechaPresentarse" class="col-sm-8">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.SolicitudPermiso.FechaPresentarse, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input id="enviarSolicitudPermisos" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" value="Enviar solicitud" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
```

Comment: Faltaria como los estas recibiendo en el controlador probablemente te este faltando el [FromBody] o [FromForm]

Comment: Ya probé con el [FromBody], se soluciono en como traía los datos de mi clase solicitud